# How to take multiple column output as one column and find top of that column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I got stuck in a scenario where I am selecting average of each column in a table. Now I want to find the top three of those columns.

here is my query:

```
SELECT AVG( `adventure` ) , AVG( `beach` ) , AVG( `culture` ) , AVG( `festival` ) , AVG( `food` ) , AVG( `fun` ) , AVG( `biking` ) , AVG( `ski` ) , AVG( `surf` ) , AVG( `family` ) , AVG( `couple` ) , AVG( `single` ) , AVG( `backpacker` )
FROM `ratings`
WHERE `reference_id`=4595
```

This query returns me average of each column. But I want to select top 3 averages only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by top 3 ? Any sort order ?

Comment: instead of selecting all columns how do I select 3 colunm with max avg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to normalized your table first but here's a query that suits your needs,

By the way it returns two columns, the names of the column on where the average was calculated and the result of the average.

```
SELECT  Category, avgVal
FROM
    (
        SELECT  'adventure' AS Category, AVG(`adventure`) AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595
        UNION
        SELECT  'beach' AS Category, AVG(`beach`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595
        UNION
        SELECT  'culture' AS Category, AVG(`culture`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'festival' AS Category, AVG(`festival`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'food' AS Category, AVG(`food`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595
        UNION
        SELECT  'fun' AS Category, AVG(`fun`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'biking' AS Category, AVG(`biking`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'ski' AS Category, AVG(`ski`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'surf' AS Category, AVG(`surf`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'family' AS Category, AVG(`family`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'couple' AS Category, AVG(`couple`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'single' AS Category, AVG(`single`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
        UNION
        SELECT  'backpacker' AS Category, AVG(`backpacker`)  AS avgVal FROM `ratings` WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
    ) s
ORDER BY avgVal DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use sub query here

```
 SELECT AVG( `adventure` ) 
       ,AVG( `beach` )
       ,AVG( `culture` )
       , AVG( `festival` )
       , AVG( `food` )
       , AVG( `fun` )
       , AVG( `biking` )
       , AVG( `ski` )
       , AVG( `surf` )
       , AVG( `family` )
       , AVG( `couple` )
       , AVG( `single` )
       , AVG( `backpacker` ) 
FROM ( SELECT adventure,beach,culture,festival,food,fun,biking,ski,surf,family,couple,single,backpacker
       FROM `ratings`
       WHERE `reference_id`=4595 
       LIMIT 0,3
) DerivedTable
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks